# Getting id of parents parent of type ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically added element called a `.courseBox`. It is a `<li>` that will reside inside a `<ul>`. This `.courseBox` item has a red "x" button on it, that will remove it from the `<ul>`. I have this function:

```
$(".basket, .semester").on("click", "button.xOut", function(){
    $(this).closest(".courseBox").remove();
    var parent = $(this).parent(); //.courseBox item
    var courseNumber = parent.attr('id');
    console.log(courseNumber);
});
```

The two classes `.basket` and `.semester` are both of the type `<ul>`. The `.courseBox` is draggable between the two. Upon dragging the `.courseBox` to a `.semester` some information is updated about the `.courseBox`. I do however not find a way of getting access to the `.semester` element from within my function above. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a really stupid problem. I removed the item on first line within the function. This line should be moved to the very end!

```
$(".basket, .semester").on("click", "button.xOut", function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent(); //.courseBox item
    var courseNumber = parent.attr('id');
    console.log(courseNumber);
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().attr("id")); //id of either basket or semester
    $(this).closest(".courseBox").remove();
});
```